# How do I plot vector functions in sagemath?

Tags: matplotlib, vector, sage

I can not seem to figure out how to plot my vector function. I define the function like this

```py
alpha = vector([sin(x), cos(x)])
```

and I can plot a single vector

```py
plot(alpha(x=1))
```

but can not plot the whole function

```py
plot(alpha(x=x))
#unable to simplify to float approximation
```

This plots the 2 functions separately

```py
plot([sin(x), cos(x)])
```

Comment: Does `parametric_plot(alpha, 0, 1)` do what you want? (Replace 0 and 1 with the desired min and max values of `x`.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as John Palmieri pointed out one can use parametric_plot to plot vector functions but you need to use a slight modified version like this

```
parametric_plot(alpha(x=x), (0,1))
```

or like this

```
parametric_plot(alpha, (x, 0, 1))
```

where 0 are the starting point and 1 the end point

the second one comes from John Palmieri as well
thank you for your help John

Comment: `parametric_plot(alpha, (x, 0, 1))` should also work.